# My Python regex code is not giving me the output as i expected

Tags: python, regex, export-to-csv

I was trying to extract and parse the words (Hostname & version) from a text file. when i run my code it writes the data into csv file but the output looks different. [image: output i had after parsing to csv]

```
 **my input file is .txt and below is the content** 
 Hostname Router1
 version 15.01
 code:
 line console 0
 logging synchronous
 exec-timeout 15 1
 usb-inactivity-timeout 15
 exec prompt timestamp
 transport preferred none

Hostname Router2
version 15.02
line vty 0 15
logging synchronous
exec-timeout 15 2
exec prompt timestamp
transport input ssh
transport preferred none
access-class REMOTE_ACCESS in

Hostname Router3
version 15
line console 0
logging synchronous
exec-timeout 15 3
usb-inactivity-timeout 15
exec prompt timestamp
transport preferred none

Hostname Router3
version 15.12
line vty 0 15
logging synchronous
exec-timeout 15 4
exec prompt timestamp
transport input ssh
transport preferred none
access-class REMOTE_ACCESS in
**Above is the sample content in my input text file**
$
import re
import csv
with open('sample5.csv','w',newline='') as output:
    HeaderFields = ['Hostname','version']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output,fieldnames=HeaderFields)
    writer.writeheader()
with open('testfile.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as input:
    for line in input.readlines():
       pattern = re.compile(r'Hostname(.*)''|''version(.*)')
       match=pattern.finditer(line)
       for match1 in match:
          with open('sample5.csv', 'a',newline='') as output:
              writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=HeaderFields)
              writer.writerow({'Hostname': match1.group(1), 'version':  
                                match1.group(2)})
```

My expected result in csv is as follows: 
[image: This should be the result in csv]

Thank You.

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: @jordanm i just updated the post. you can have it

Comment: the simplest fix is to replace alternative with endline in the pattern. If you prefer your pattern, inside of the loop you can populate the dictionary slowly column by column, and write down only when both column ready

Comment: @serge I dint understand what you said. i am just learning python. Can you explain in detail. thanks

Comment: The simplest fix is presented in my answer

Comment: Hi it worked on Mac but not working on windows

Comment: It only worked on example I gave. If there are three lines in between it is not matching. Any reason? And if replace ‘version’ with ‘ASA version’ not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code fails because in each iteration you read only one line (which can contain host or version but not both, yet you write data into csv. Let's iterate through all the text while matching twoliners:
with first line Hostname.. and second line version... \n works as line break for Windows (I hear Mac uses \r not sure). Now since you match twoliners you can grab both router and version from same match object.

```
with open('testfile.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as input:
       txt = input.read()
       pattern = re.compile(r'Hostname (.*)(\r\n?|\n)version (.*)')
       match=pattern.finditer(txt)
       for match1 in match:
          with open('sample5.csv', 'a',newline='') as output:
             writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=HeaderFields)
             writer.writerow({'Hostname': match1.group(1), 'version':  
                            match1.group(3)})
```

Comment: can you add an explanation for why this is correct?

Comment: @Serge i don't see anything in output csv file.

Comment: @Serge i don't think '\n' would make any operation as it is a newline character.

Comment: The code would not work if router and version are separated with few lines, while your idea could, with appropriate fixes

Comment: @Serge Same i don't get any output in csv file other than Headers.

Comment: It worked for my computer, though I did not read file just defined string

Comment: what os do you use?

Comment: I use Mac OS in my laptop. In office windows

Comment: try crossplatform version now

Comment: @serge what is crossplatform version ?

Comment: in the answer, I added \r

Comment: @Serge now i only get Router column. version column is empty

Comment: did you replace group(2) with group(3) as in above?

Comment: I will check your comments next afternoon, that s really late time, and I have an important meeting tomorrow

Comment: @Serge thanks hope we would figure this out. thanks for try.

Comment: make sure you replaced group(2) with group(3) as I added another group for breakline expression

Comment: Yes thank you. As I said it only worked for Mac not for windows.

Comment: Ok I will try again.

Comment: It worked. My python ide has some problem. After I reinstalled it worked.